# Tmux remapping prefix key

Tags: tmux

What does the following section do in the tmux config file?

```
# remap prefix
unbind C-b
set -g prefix C-a
bind C-a send-prefix
```

It seems to me the `unbind` removes the default `C-a` as prefix. But then how do the other two work? (Also, is the last line necessary?)

Comment: It remaps the prefix from `C-b` to `C-a` - but I can't tell you the exact meaning of each line.

Answer (score 1):

This sequence changes the prefix from `C-b` to `C-a` and also moves the default `send-prefix` binding from `C-b` to `C-a`.

> unbind C-b

Remove the default `C-b` binding which is for `send-prefix`. This was present so `C-b C-b` sent a `C-b` to the application inside tmux.

> set -g prefix C-a

Set the prefix to `C-a` instead of the default `C-b`.

> bind C-a send-prefix

Bind `C-a` to `send-prefix`, so that `C-a C-a` sends a `C-a` to the application inside tmux.